# jQuery Validate plugin unable to scroll to field with validation error in iOS 8 Safari

Tags: jquery, ios8, jquery-validate, mobile-safari

I am using the **[jQuery Validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)** for validating form input (user info, address, credit card details etc.)

The form is on the **mobile version of the site.**

When you fill the form and scroll down to the 'purchase' button at the bottom of the page, if you have an invalid field (e.g. you forgot to enter any content), clicking the 'purchase' button will focus the invalid input and scroll up to that input. This is all done by the jQuery Validation plugin.

This works in most mobile browsers that I have tested (Android/Chrome, Windows Phone, mobile Safari iOS 7 and below). However any **mobile Safari browsers on iOS8+** are not scrolling. The input is focussed and the on-screen keyboard pops up, however **scrolling to the input doesn't happen**.

I've investigated several other threads discussing similar but slightly different issues and cannot find a solution to the issue!

Any help would be greatly received on this one!

Comment: jQuery Validate plugin has nothing to do with scrolling the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Title: jQuery Validate plugin unable to scroll to field with validation error in iOS 8 Safari

Actually, that's not a feature of this plugin for any browser.

[The jQuery Validate plugin's source code](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js) verifies that it only brings "focus" to the invalid field, and **has absolutely nothing to do with scrolling the page**.  If your mobile browser is scrolling, it's only a feature of the browser to scroll to the element in focus.

You will have to write your own custom [`invalidHandler` function](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#invalidhandler) to find the first element with an `error` class and scroll to it.

> Callback for custom code when an invalid form is submitted.

```
invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
    // your code for finding invalid element and scrolling
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad you clarified what is doing the scrolling I kind of knew that already but wasn't explaining very well and certainly didn't know how to override it with the invalidHandler. Great answer :)